# ZipFileException upon undeployment of WAR in JBoss 5.1

Tags: java, jboss, centos, aspectj

I've got a standard WAR application that is working well under JBoss 5.1 and Ubuntu linux 12.10.

However, when I try to deploy the same application on CentOS 5.2, I face the following exception on stop (undeploy) operation:

> java.lang.Error: Error visiting
>   DelegatingHandler@458087116[path=app.war/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjtools.jar
>   context=file:/jboss/server/deploy/
>   real=file:/jboss/server/deploy/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjtools.jar
>   Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:127) at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:143) at
>   org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipFileWrapper.ensureZipFile(ZipFileWrapper.java:175)
>   at
>   org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipFileWrapper.acquire(ZipFileWrapper.java:245)
>   at
>   org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.initEntries(ZipEntryContext.java:484)
>   at
>   org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.ensureEntries(ZipEntryContext.java:619)
>   ... 58 more

The aspectjtools.jar is required for load-time weaving AOP.

- I'm using aspectjtools 1.6.2, but I also tried with latest version 1.7.1, same problem.
- I've double-checked the ZIP file integrity of that JAR many times, integrity ok.
- I've created a small application that unzip the war with java.util.zip, no exceptions.
- I've checked that the unix file descriptor limit was high enough, max limit set.
- The user starting the JBoss JVM has all the rights on the server directory.
- I've searched for irregularites in aspectjtools.jar, nothing special.

Still can figure out what the problem is and as there are 0 google links for this, I'm wondering if I'm not doing something wrong! I'm running out of ideas, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using exactly the same JDK to run the JBoss'es (for Jboss 5.1, it's recommended the Oracle JDK v. 1.6s)?

Comment: 1.6.0_13 is used on CentOS (server) and on local Ubuntu (dev) I use 1.6.0_32. I deploy on CentOS based on a CI build that shares JDK with target server (v13).

Comment: And what about the vendors (OpenJDK, IBM, Oracle ...)? You'd better use the Oracle version of the JDK in both environments. It looks like a problem with the Java distribution you've installed in your server.

Comment: Only oracle everywhere. The exception come from a native method, which could be affected by the JVM I agree, but why the heck JBoss has to fail an undeploy operation so badly!

Comment: mmm, in that case it doesn't seem a JVM problem, but since it's a native method, maybe it's related with the OS (CentOS) zip libraries. Have you tried to unpack the jar and repack it, and include it to the project?

Comment: I've `unzip` it and realized some files had root-only permissions set on them (ZIP is apparently supporting unix permission). I've `chmod` to 777 everything in the WAR and in the aspectjtools.jar and repacked both with CentOS's `zip` tool. But still, I got the same exception!

Comment: I'm in desperation! I think I will suggest moving from load-time weaving to post-compile weaving and avoid this messy jar file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the glitch: `aspectjtools-1.6.2.jar` contains another JAR `/ant_tasks/resources-ant.jar` that seems to be causing the problem. I removed the folder `/ant_tasks` from the jar and now I can include this in my war files, deploy/undeploy in JBoss and the stack trace disappeared. 
Not sure what caused this exactly, as it looks like a combination of JBoss (VFS), jar of jar and CentOS.